# difference between properties and tags in the upper right corner

Tags: org-mode, pdf, beamer

I dont get the difference between the actual property, enabling the respective funtionality and the tag on the right upper side?

```
*** Number 5                                         :B_example:
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_env: example
:END:

5 can only be divided evenly by 1 or 5, so it is a prime number.
```

Can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 3):

See the footnote in the [Frames and Blocks in Beamer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Frames-and-Blocks-in-Beamer.html#Frames-and-Blocks-in-Beamer) section of the Org mode manual:

> (1) If ‘BEAMER_ENV’ is set, Org export adds ‘B_environment’ tag to
> make it visible.  The tag serves as a visual aid and has no semantic
> relevance.